# Can I move a tab in Safari with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, safari, tabs

In Safari, with multiple tabs open, I want to be able to change the order of the tabs with a keyboard shortcut.

For example, if the third tab of four is active:

```
A B [C] D
```

…how can I move the third tab to the second spot, *without using the mouse/trackpad*?

```
A [C] B D
```

Note: I'm not asking how to switch which tab is active. I want to change the order of the tabs within a browser window.

I'd like to be able to do this without installing a plugin or browser extension, if possible.

Comment: You're gonna have to drag it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible but apparently you can do it in Chrome. I'm not sure you are in the right sandbox for "bend to your will" type mods